# Determine whether a list contains a particular sequence

Tags: python

Allowing wraparound, the sequence `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]` contains the sequence `[7, 11, 2]`.

I'm looking for compact/pythonic way to code this, rather than an optimally-efficient way. (Unless I need the efficiency, I usually gravitate to the path of least ASCII).

An obvious method would be as follows (I provide three different ways to code it):

```
def Contains(L, s):
    L_extended = L+L[0:len(s)]

    for i in xrange( len(L) ):
        if L_extended[i:i+len(s)] == s:
            return True

    return False


def Contains2(L, s):
    L_extended = L+L[0:len(s)]

    return next( \
        ( True for i in xrange(len(L))  if  L_extended[i:i+len(s)] == s ), \
        False \
        )


def Contains3(L, s):
    L_extended = L+L[0:len(s)]

    try:
        next( i  for  i in xrange(len(L))  if  L_extended[i:i+len(s)] == s )
    except StopIteration:
        return False

    return True

print Contains3( [1,2,3,4,5], [1,3] )   # False
print Contains3( [1,2,3,4,5], [2,3] )   # True
print Contains3( [1,2,3,4,5], [4,5,1] ) # True
```

My preference is for the first, but Python is full of pleasant surprises -- can anyone see a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: What is `b` ? Does your code work at all ?

Comment: It certainly doesn't cover the wraparound case

Comment: Sorry, code has been fixed now!

Comment: Your question is now on topic, but I regret to see that you set compact code above clean, readable and optimal code.

Comment: I like to put clarity first. For my work I don't need optimal efficiency. Compact means concise, and often this helps improve clarity. Certainly I wouldn't sacrifice clarity for saving ASCII. That's my bad wording in the question, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in your comments above, the first is the cleanest way you came up with.

Instead of writing your own logic, Python has a built-in library `difflib` that contains the [`SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) class. You can use this to find the longest match between two iterables:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def contains(main_list, sub_list, junk=None):
    sub_len = len(sub_list)
    extended = main_list + main_list[:sub_len]

    sequence = SequenceMatcher(junk, extended, sub_list)
    return sequence.get_longest_match(0, len(extended), 0, sub_len).size == sub_len
```

My only qualm with `get_longest_match` is that its parameters are **ALL** positional arguments and are thus required. I would prefer the API assume we want the entire length of both iterables searched. Instead of using `get_longest_match` you could instead use the `get_matching_blocks` function (which returns tuples) then iterate through those until the corresponding tuple value is equal to `sub_len`.

By using `SequenceMatcher` you also get the flexibility to declare what 'junk' you want the class to ignore. So say you want to find the longest match between the two lists, but you don't care about `1` or `2`. You would simply pass the lambda:

```
lambda num: num in [1, 2]
```

as the `junk` parameter.

---

Now that I've given my structure recommendation, I want to give some style pointers.

First of all, take a look at [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python style guide. It gives a great reference to how your code should look. Here are some places your code strays from the Python conventions:

1. Use descriptive variable names. Single letter variable names are typically frowned-upon. When naming, err on the side of being **too** descriptive instead of too brief.
2. Use `underscores_in_names` for basically everything in Python. The only aberration from this rule is class names which are written in `PascalCase`.

   Also, variable and function/method names should be lowercase. Conventionally, uppercase names are saved for constants. So by convention, you `L` variable is considered constant.
3. Your spacing is quite nice; except for a few occasions where you place a single space after an opening paren and before the close paren. PEP8 actually labels that style as a [pet peeve](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements).
4. Multi-line statement happen. PEP8 purposefully [takes a neutral stance](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) on how those should be formatted. However, Python is quite lenient in terms of newlines in statements, so more than likely, there is a better way to format your multi-line statements without escaping the newlines.

   ```
   def Contains2(L, s):
       L_extended = L+L[0:len(s)]

       return next((True for i in xrange(len(L)) 
                    if  L_extended[i:i+len(s)] == s), False)
   ```